# how to keep select option when click button submit ...when click button don't save my select

Tags: php

```
            <select name="type_of_room" style="color:#fefefe;  background-color:#2C3E50;">
             <option selected="selected" value="0">...Choose Type Of Room...</option>
     <option value="1">Special_Room</option>
             <option value="2" >Single_Room</option>
             <option value="3" >Dual_Room</option>
             <option value="4" >Triple_Room </option>
        </select>  <input type="submit" name="show_detail" value="Show Detail" style="margin: 20px; background-color: #f2dede;"/>
```

when click button don't save my select

Comment: What do you mean by "save my select"? Will the submit button take you back to the same page and you want to mark that option as selected?

Comment: after select and click button the drop down list change to the selected vaue 0 and not that i select

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with this one:

```
<?php
$selectedValue = '0';
if(isset($_GET['type_of_room'])) {
  $selectedValue = $_GET['type_of_room'];
}
?>
<select name="type_of_room" style="color:#fefefe;  background-color:#2C3E50;">
  <option <?php if($selectedValue == '0'): ?>selected="selected"<?php endif; ?> value="0">...Choose Type Of Room...</option>
  <option <?php if($selectedValue == '1'): ?>selected="selected"<?php endif; ?> value="1">Special_Room</option>
  <option <?php if($selectedValue == '1'): ?>selected="selected"<?php endif; ?> value="2" >Single_Room</option>
  <option <?php if($selectedValue == '3'): ?>selected="selected"<?php endif; ?> value="3" >Dual_Room</option>
  <option <?php if($selectedValue == '4'): ?>selected="selected"<?php endif; ?> value="4" >Triple_Room </option>
</select>
```